# JavaScript making something unnecessarily complicated

Tags: javascript

I see code blocks all the time where people make it unnecessarily complicated. What is the reason for this?

Example:

```
const greet = function (greeting) {
return function (name) {
console.log(`${greeting} ${name}`)
 }
}

const greeterHey = greet('Hey');
greeterHey('test')
```

instead of something like this

```
const greet = function (greeting, name) {
console.log(`${greeting} ${name}`)
}

const greeterHey = greet('Hey', 'test');
```

What is it all about? Does it have anything to do with the fact that when you edit the code block later, it's easier?

Comment: The first method lets you make one-argument functions for "Hey!", "Hola!", "What's up dude?", etc, with a single function call for each. In other words, `greet()` can be called as many times as desired to make as many different greeting functions as desired.

Comment: This sounds really useless for the effort

Comment: It is useless if you're making useless functions like in this example, but in general it is an extremely powerful mechanism.

Comment: Yes this was not an example I use this function all the time in real world

Comment: Okay.... So why do you use it all the time in the real world if it seems unnecessarily complicated to you?

Comment: A lot (and I mean a **lot**) of functional programming uses single-argument functions, so much so that people are used to it and do it out of habit. As code becomes more complex, this convention DOES become useful.  See https://youtube.com/watch?v=iZLP4qOwY8I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably an example of function currying or higher-order function, a technique in Functional Programming Paradigm. Curryinng is IMO quite probably the single most important thing in Functional programming with Haskell for example.

The example is probably just for easy demonstration, however, the technique is quite powerful if used in correct situations.

By currying multiple-parameter function into chains of one-argument functions, you can create what I called "Niche function"

```js
const greet = function (greeting) {
  return function (name) {
    console.log(`${greeting}, ${name}`)
  }
}

// greetWithHello kinda retains the same logic as `greet`, but now has become more "niche"
// because you can only greet with "Hello"
const greetWithHello = greet("Hello"); //greetWithHello is a FUNCTION
greetWithHello("Ben") // "Hello, Ben"
greetWitHello("Bob") // "Hello, Bob"

const greetWithBadaboom = greet("Badaboom")
```

As you can imagine, instead of keep writing `greet("Hello", "Ben")` and `greet("Hello", "Bob")`, you now have a more reusable `greetWithHello` function.

Compared this with the un-curried version

```js
const greet2(phrase, name) {
  console.log(`${phrase}, ${name}`)
}

const greetWithHello2 = (name) => {
  return greet2("Hello", name)
}

const greetWithBadaboom2 = (name) => {
  return greet2("Badaboom", name)
}
```

As you can see, much less composable and readable than the curried version, and this is just for 2 parameters. This is why functional programming patterns can be very useful when working with functions

I only know this from college and never actually used it myself, but I guess libraries with higher-order-functions may utilize this

Comment: Furthermore, consider an array of "seminar" objects where `seminar.students` is an array of names. `const greetSeminar = ({students}) => students.forEach(greetWithHello);` allows for `seminars.forEach(greetSeminar)`. Or, you could do `const actOnStudents = (seminars, functionPerStudentName) = seminars.forEach(({students}) => students.forEach(functionPerStudentName));` and you now have a way to do *something* per student in all seminars.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to something called "closures" which, in short, allows to create functions that return functions, and those retain the values you provided, variables or constants alike.

In other languages, variables or constants created inside the scope/block of a function only live during the execution of such function. In JavaScript, when using this syntax, a "lexical environment" is created, and the returned function can also access values out of its own scope/environment.

As stated in the other answers, it's a very useful characteristic when used correctly in higher-order functions.

There are some examples and a more clear explanation in the MDN page about closures:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures